# neovim screen lagging when switching mode from insert to normal

Tags: tmux, iterm2, neovim, coc.nvim

I'm running neovim + coc + tmux in iTerm2. Sometimes I'm seeing the screen lag a lot, which leads to overlap content, such as the selected content and the status line...

Not sure what's cause the issue, can you please help me understand how to debug this?

[image]

Comment: Does this happen when you are not using tmux?

Comment: not that I remember of

Answer (score 4):

adding a

`set -s escape-time 0`

to my .tmux.conf file fixed the delay problem when hitting the esc key

Comment: Thanks, Martin, I will give it a try, I had `escape-time` as `1`, I thought I was enough